# Web scraping vivino returns less records than expected

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

Trying to scrape vivino data
My code is

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import requests
import time
wine_df = []
#Create Empty DataFrame To Append To
wine_cols = ['Winery','Wine','Rating','Review_Count','Region','SubRegion', 'Price', 'id']
wine_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=wine_cols)

for x in range(1,100):
    r = requests.get(
    "https://www.vivino.com/api/explore/explore",
    params = {
        "country_codes[]":"it",
        "page": x,
    },
        headers= {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0"
    }

    )
    results = [
        (
        t["vintage"]["wine"]["winery"]["name"], 
        f'{t["vintage"]["wine"]["name"]} {t["vintage"]["year"]}',
        t["vintage"]["statistics"]["ratings_average"],
        t["vintage"]["statistics"]["ratings_count"],
        t["vintage"]["wine"]["region"]["country"]["name"],
        t["vintage"]["wine"]["region"]["name"],
        t["price"]["amount"],
        t["vintage"]["wine"]["type_id"]
        )
        for t in r.json()["explore_vintage"]["matches"]
    ]
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame(results,columns=wine_cols)
    wine_df = wine_df.append(temp_df, ignore_index=True)
```

When calling `r.text`, info on region returns "country": "code":"it", "name":"Italy", "native_name":"Italia", "seo_name":"italy", "currency": "code":"EUR", "name":"Euros", "prefix":"€","suffix":null}, "regions_count":563, "users_count":4239750, **"wines_count":380594**, but info on my request returns "records_matched":12849. Same with any region, the number of records matched does not equal wines in the region, whether it is country with many wines or country with little wines

Answer (score 0):

It's API we can just get 2050 records only after that we got only duplicates, i have tried different methods like changing the search fields but it's getting under 2050 we got wine ids from somewhere then we can use another API
[https://api.vivino.com/wines/{wineid}](https://api.vivino.com/wines/%7Bwineid%7D)

Comment: This response may provide some insight into the underlying issues of the original question, but it it's not an answer and should be left instead as a comment on the question. Also, it's written as though it may be the same person as the OP.